# PHP Every 7th and 8th table cell style in For Loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, calendar

I know you can set every nth row or cell of a table to have certain attributes in a for Loop

```
   if($ib % 7){
   echo '<td>'.$ib.'</td>';
   }
  else{
  echo '<td bgcolor="005082"></td>';
  }
```

But can you do the same for the next row aswell. In other words can I set every 7th and 8th table cell next to each other to have the same colour?  I'm building a calendar and want to highlight the weekend.

Comment: Use CSS for this purpose.

Comment: `$ib % 7 or $ib % 8`?

Comment: Wait ... there are 8 days in a week now?

Comment: @CD001 Didn't you get the memo? Our overlords have unanimously decided that weekends are too long. The weekend has been halved in length in order to add a new working day after Friday.

Comment: @CD001I don't think so, but maybe we missed something?

Comment: Every `7th and 8th`? I hope you mean every `6th and 7th`

Comment: @CD001I It's because the array that I'm drawing the textual days of the week from starts with Sunday and ends with Saturday hence Saturday is 7 and Sunday is 8 in a sense.  It was the easiest way I could think to short hand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like

```
if($ib % 7 == 0 || $ib % 7 == 1){
    echo '<td bgcolor="005082"></td>';
}
else {
    echo '<td>'.$ib.'</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would achieve it using **CSS** [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
table tr td:nth-child(7n+7), table tr td:nth-child(7n+8) {
    background: #005082;
}
```

> I selected 6th & 7th elements as a week lasts 7 days...